# How to get BER for QPSK modulation?

Tags: gnuradio, usrp, modulation, ber

I am trying to compare data before modulation using the BER block. But my probability turns out to be very bad. It should be close to 0.

Based on the scheme from the [Simulation example: BPSK Demodulator](https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php?title=Simulation_example:_BPSK_Demodulation),([Block scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A857K.png))I am trying to calculate BER. The diagram in the figure. What am I doing wrong?[BER](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBk7G.png) Why do I get BER = -1.7 (this number is a power of 10)?

In the future I plan to use USRP instead of Channel Model and transfer text files. Is my scheme correct in general?

Comment: Uff, sorry, as a German with a bit of historical awareness, not going to help someone with the nick "[Ubermensch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%9Cbermensch#Use_by_the_Nazis)". Not funny.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Sorry. This nickname is a reference to Nietzsche. Thus Spake Zarathustra

Comment: I can see that, but you need to consider historical context – some words and symbols have just been occupied by the third Reich ideology. Can't have run around with a specific shape of cross on an armband, even if it's an ancient Indian symbol.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I didn't even think that someone would associate my nickname with the third Reich.
In that case, can you help with my question? I've been figuring this out for 2 months. I need it for my thesis. 
I can resend the question with a different nickname.

Comment: Question for clarification: This block scheme under link is created/configured by you, or is reference one from tutorials.
A general sugestion I have is doing small baby steps. Start without sinhronisation and guarantee that source bits and received bits are aligned. The RRC filter in the transmitter introduces group delay which depends on number of taps and has to be figured  and skipped at receiver.